# How do I determine what hardware is present?

Tags: usb, hardware, serial-port, tether

I'm looking to see what serial ports, USB and ethernet ports are available and what they are labeled as.

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
lshw
```

what you're looking for?

From the manual

```
DESCRIPTION
   lshw is a small tool to extract detailed information on the hardware configuration  of  the  machine.  It  can
   report  exact  memory  configuration,  firmware version, mainboard configuration, CPU version and speed, cache
   configuration, bus speed, etc. on DMI-capable x86 or IA-64 systems and on some PowerPC machines  (PowerMac  G4
   is known to work).

   It currently supports DMI (x86 and IA-64 only), OpenFirmware device tree (PowerPC only), PCI/AGP, CPUID (x86),
   IDE/ATA/ATAPI, PCMCIA (only tested on x86), SCSI and USB.
```

Comment: I don't believe it shows the ports. All those other details are nice but, they are not what I am interested in at the moment.